# Delete a Batch file variable in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently trying to delete a variable from a batch file which is in a text file

e.g. delete %variable%

where %variable% = "test"

So the batch script would delete the instance of "test" in the specified text file

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set variable=test
for /f "delims=" %%l in (foo.txt) do (
  set "line=%%f"
  echo !line:%variable%=!
)
```

Comment: Hi, I got invalid parameter to SETLOCAL

Answer (score 0):

To avoid potential special character issues with the string you are searching for, it may be better to just call findstr directly like this:

```
type input.txt | findstr /b /e /v "remove_line" > input_without_remove_line.txt
```

/b and /e together will only match if the "remove_line" is the only text on a line.  /v will switch the output to only print all lines that do not match.

If you are sure you're not passing special characters, it is pretty easy to wrap that in a small batch and replace remove line with %1 or %* to use your passed parameters.

Unfortunately, you will need to use a temporary file - replacing the file in place doesn't work with the DOS output redirection.

If you were wanting to delete all instances of a specified word within any line, batch and findstr are probably not the way to do it.  Look at sed, which can do much more and is freely available.  If you can't install another utility, even vbscript using cscript would be a better way to do this than batch.