# Directly delete a text string  from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to delete a variable that is defined within a batch file for example: %bad%

Although is there a tool that can directly remove the variable from a text file.

I am OK with using GNUWin tools if needed

Comment: Could you please tell us how [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225646/delete-a-batch-file-variable-in-a-text-file/6225685#6225685) was not helpful for you?

Comment: It Didnt, work, I annoted that on the comments

Comment: Why did you accept it then? You didn't have to do so. Also, your last comment was: `thanks, but it doesnt seem to work`. This doesn't help the person who answered you to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you could use sed for windows...

```
type somefile.txt | sed "s/bad text/good text/g" >> new-file.txt
```